# I tried to make a generator that takes names out of a list along with an ordered number

Tags: python, random

So to be more specific, I'm hosting a draft and I am trying to create a generator that will place each person into a specific team. After some time with Google, I was able to get the names to appear at random but the problem is that I get some names to repeat.
    import random
    from random import choice
    from random import shuffle

```
stream_start = input("Welome to the Odin Open x KickPunchShootemup draft!"
                    " The draft will start soon so please enjoy the music in the meantime!")

reminder = input ("Alright so if you miss anything I say, I will have it typed out here."
                           " First we are going to determine who gets the first pick."
                           " Then we will proceed with who goes onto which team.")

players = [

'Nets',
'Mazen9',
'Skoogman',
'Beastslicer',
'GDXDEV!',
'ShadeRequiem',
'Raixia Mao',
'Abigial Flerina',
'HJC7',
'SPF',
'-Maverick-',
'Mando_Savage94',
'Brigand',
'iEnglishBetter',
'HidakaFlocka',
'AG Scorcho',
'eMzez',
'Seducier',
]

for pick in players:
   for order in range(1, 13, +1):
       if order == 1:
           input("The number 1 pick of the draft is...")
           input(random.sample(players, k = 1))
       elif order == 2:
           input("The number 2 pick of the draft is...")
           input(random.sample(players, k = 1))
       else:
           input("The number {} pick of the draft is...".format(order))
           input(random.sample(players, k =1))
```

I read that random.sample prevents items from being repeated but I still get some regardless. I'm not sure if what I did disregards that or not. Any sort of help is appreciated!

Comment: Read about `random.shuffle()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a generator you can do something like this:

```
from random import randint

def draft(players):
    pos = 0
    while len(players) > 0:
        i = randint(0, len(players) - 1)
        yield (pos, players.pop(i))
        pos += 1

for draft_position, player in draft(players):
    print '{0}: {1}'.format(draft_position, player)
```

Or, as Amaro suggests in the comments, just shuffle your list of players and read them out in order.

```
from random import shuffle

shuffle(players)
for draft_position, player in enumerate(players):
    print '{0}: {1}'.format(draft_position, player)
```